# The importance of a premise sentence or two premise sentences

Tags: style

I hope my question is not off the site's topics.

When writing one or two *premise* sentences for a story, may the premise sentences be in the first POV or third POV, or either POV may be used?

Do the premise sentences come in the opening paragraph of my story or before outside the narrative?

I've searched the answers at multiple places; It's just not clear to me.

Thank you

Comment: This question isn't dealing with the nuts and bolts of the English *language,* but with styles of writing. It's thus more on-topic on Writers. However, it might be improved with actual examples of what you're uncertain of.

Comment: Amadeus confirmed. "But you don't put the premise INTO the story, it is only a tool for the author to maintain consistency and stay on track when writing the story." I did right in my last story. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A [premise statement](http://www.writersdigest.com/writing-articles/by-writing-goal/improve-my-writing/the_premise_of_your_story) (read the link, it is short) is not typically IN your story at all, not before it, not in the prose.

As the link says:

> Every story has one premise. Only one. This premise is the underlying idea of your story-the foundation that supports your entire plot.
>
> If you can establish what your premise is at the beginning of your project, you will have an easier time writing your story. That”s because the fundamental concept you create in advance will drive the actions of your characters.

I disagree with this notion that every story has a premise and ONLY ONE premise, but certainly you can devise a plot around some premise and devise perfect characters to populate that plot.

But you don't put the premise INTO the story, it is only a tool for the author to maintain consistency and stay on track when writing the story.